# How to set the parameter of LSTM

Tags: machine-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have my data in following ways, for example:

```
index:[   1,         2,      3,       4,       5,    ...]
value:[[1*1024],[1*1024],[1*1024],[1*1024],[1*1024], ...]
label:[total 10 categories, one_hot for each data]
```

for my problem, my sequence length is fixed, lets say, every sequence has 5 elements with dimension of 1024.

I want to use LSTM to build the model, feed in sequence [1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10] and so on, then the model will give me the corresponding label [1*,2*,3*,4*,5*],[6*,7*,8*,9*,10*] for example. (* means the corresponding label for that index)

so here I have few questions:
1>what is the input size? [5,1024],[1024,5]???
2>when to set "return_sequences = True", i noticed that this option will affect the output shape o LSTM.

can give me some guide on this...really got confused.

Comment: which language is is? python?

Answer (score 0):

My example is in Keras and Python:
First of all you have to prepare your data in the format: [how many training samples you have, how long your timesteps are (1024 in this case), and how many inputs you have (5 I think)].

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(64, input_shape=(1024, 5)))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
adam = Adam()
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=adam, metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(train_data, train_label, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=2)
```

I don´t know if i got your input format right, but you can adapt it, as i explained how it should look.

Comment: thanks ! holy sht I think they need to update the keras doc a bit...really no clue about how to do that...thanks again!

Comment: but i think the input_shape should be [5,1024]? i only have 5 words in each sentence and each words is in a form of 1024 feature?

Comment: well, if your sequence is 5 words (timesteps) long, and every word (timestep) you have 1024 data, than yes